# What are docker-proxy processes for

Tags: docker

When I look at all running processes on my Linux machine, there are quite a few `docker-proxy` processes. It seems like every running container (port) results in one docker-proxy!

Problem is I cannot find any documentation which processes docker actually starts and how their relationship/usage is.

Does anyone know if there is any documentation on that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A full explanation of the `docker-proxy` is available [here](https://windsock.io/the-docker-proxy/).

The summary is that the proxy is used to handle connections originating from the local machine that might otherwise not pass through the `iptables` rules that Docker configures to handle port forwarding, or when Docker has been configured such that it does not manipulate `iptables` at all.

Comment: Link is not working now, can you please provide a working doc reference. Thanks.

Comment: The link was still working for me, but I've updated to point directly at the article rather than at the listing of tagged articles.

Comment: Thanks, its working now. Sorry, may be something went wrong at my end. Thanks for the reply.